# Default user for zeppelin hortonworks sandbox

Tags: linux, apache-zeppelin, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-sandbox

I have installed the sandbox-hdp sandbox on docker, after starting the container:

```
docker start -p 8080:8080 sandbox-hdp
```

Which starts running at port 8080:

```
96f221ec7978        hortonworks/sandbox-hdp:3.0.1   "/usr/sbin/init"    12 hours ago        Up 15 minutes       22/tcp, 4200/tcp, 8080/tcp   sandbox-hdp
```

On that address in the browser I get the starting page on zeppelin:

[image]

Which requires a user name and password that I do not have, I have tried with:

```
admin
admin
```

which does not work

Comment: Did you try `admin-hortonworks1` ? Otherwise, I've managed to 'reset' the password by following these steps: [reset admin password](https://www.cloudera.com/tutorials/learning-the-ropes-of-the-hdp-sandbox.html#admin-password-reset)

Answer (score 2):

@LuisRamonRamierzRodriquez check the zeppelin shiro.ini config for users:

```
[users]
# List of users with their password allowed to access Zeppelin.
# To use a different strategy (LDAP / Database / ...) check the shiro doc at http://shiro.apache.org/configuration.html#Configuration-INISections
admin = admin, admin
user1 = user1, role1, role2
user2 = user2, role3
user3 = user3, role2
```